# Best way to create objects from different data formats

Tags: c#, design-patterns

For a project I'm working on, I need to create objects using different source data formats, more or less like this:

```
public class FooService
{
    protected DataFormat Format { get; set; }

    public FooService(DataFormat format = DataFormat.Json)
    {
        Format = format;
    }

    public Foo GetFoo(int id)
    {
        string content = GetContentInFormat("someuri/foo/" + id, Format);

        // Something here must create a "Foo" object
        // based on Format, which could be Json, Xml or other
    }
}

public enum DataFormat
{
    Json,
    Xml
}
```

I know I could:

**1)** Have different methods and choose the right one based on Format:

```
switch (Format)
{
    case DataFormat.Xml:
       return CreateFooFromXml(content);
    case DataFormat.Json:
       return CreateFooFromJson(content);
    default:
       throw new Exception("Invalid format.");
}
```

*Cons:* there will be at least 8 different types that will be created this way, so I need something more extensible and maintainable.

**2)** Make FooService an interface or abstract class and implement concrete classes, one for each format.

*Cons:* business logic in *all* classes will *always* be the same, except for the class instantiation. It may be confusing having `JsonFooService` and `XmlFooService`.

I would like to know what's the best solution for this from an extensibility and maintainability point of view.

Comment: To clarify, you need a service that can create an object based on varying input (JSON, XML, etc)? So, the object returned will always be the same, and only the input will differ? This does sound a lot like you have things a little confused in your code, and with some reorganization, you will just need to use the strategy pattern'

Comment: @JustinPihony I know it can seem quite confusing, but yes, that's what I need. The problem is that there are many different objects that will be created using this method and I feel strategy is not the best fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're clearly talking [creational patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern) here, but I don't think we know enough about the complexity of the Foo's to clearly recommend one over another. Luckily there aren't that many of the GoF creational patterns, so you can read up on all of them in fairly short order. It appears you already understand the [factory-method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern, so you might skip to [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) and [builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to see whether they fit the bill better.

Tips from the builder wiki:

> - Builder focuses on constructing a complex object step by step. Abstract Factory emphasizes a family of product objects (either simple
>     or complex). Builder returns the product as a final step, but as far
>     as the Abstract Factory is concerned, the product gets returned
>     immediately.
> - Builder often builds a [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).
> - Often, designs start out using Factory Method (less complicated, more customizable, subclasses proliferate) and evolve toward Abstract
>     Factory, Prototype, or Builder (more flexible, more complex) as the
>     designer discovers where more flexibility is needed.
> - Sometimes creational patterns are complementary: Builder can use one of the other patterns to implement which components are built.
>     Abstract Factory, Builder, and Prototype can use Singleton in their
>     implementations.
> - Builders are good candidates for a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making Format an enum, you could make it an interface (`IFormat`).

Then, for each format, create a concrete class (e.g., `JsonFormat`) that implements `IFormat`.

Each concrete class should have only what is unique to the particular format, such as how to find the element/record given an `Id`.

This is the "strategy pattern": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: I don't want to mix up the logic to get the data (code I posted) and the logic to create the instance from that. That's part of the problem.

Comment: It's part of the problem that "Foo" is not the only object that has to be created this way. Should I have a method in "JsonFormat" for each type that has to be created? I feel like something is wrong / missing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use case for the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), which deals with algorithms which can be selected at runtime. Switch-cases and long if/else if/else conditions can be transformed to elegant maintainable code

In case you want to dynamically switch out the data format generators, you can look at options like [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) which is a way to extend your application to discover new extensions without any configuration

Answer (score 0):

specifically, you could use IOC (e.g. autofac) and some type of injection (as I see you're close to that thinking already),
to **register all your available formats services on startup**
(from config or simply an easy one-off initialization that's easy to maintain over time as you add new types)...
as e.g. implementing IOutputFormatService interface
You can then dynamically round them up (e.g. resolve, list out all implemented formats)
and each can 'do the job' via the common interface - or if you 'know them' you could also access them specifically, like IJsonOutputFormatInterface if needed.
If/when you add (or remove) new - it's just the configuration part that changes
And as others mentioned, you only need to code each service to do what's specific to it, format rendering etc.
note: reflection is not required, it's more a concept that's important

Answer (score 0):

The pattern factory method is what you want. The pattern itself will not remove the `switch` statement, but it will only exist in one place.

However, you can combine the pattern with a bit of reflection to remove the switch statement.

Code (pseudocode)

```
public class FormatterFactory
{
  Dictionary<string, IFormatter> _formatters;

  public void FormatterFactory()
  {
      var baseType = typeof(IFormatter);
      var formatterTypes = AppDomain
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes.Where(x=>baseType.IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract);

       // convention based. Each formatter must be named like "JsonFormatter"
       foreach (var type in formatterTypes) 
       {
           _formatters.Add(type.Name.Replace("Formatter", "").ToLower(), type), 
       }
  }
  public IFormatter Create(string formatName)
  {
      var type = _formatters[formatName.ToLower());
      return (IFormatter)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var factory = new FormatterFactory();
var json = factory.Create("json").Serialize(myObject);
```